# print currently evaluated params during scipy minimization

Tags: python, scipy, parameters, minimization

I am trying to minimize a function in Python using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, to determine four distinct parameters.

I would like to print the currently evaluated params at each step of the optimisation algorithm, so I can use them to make my initial guess better.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `callback` keyword argument.

`scipy.optimize.minimize` can take a keyword argument `callback`. This should be a function that accepts, as input, the current vector of parameters. This function is called after every iteration.

For instance,

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(xs):
    """ Function to optimize. """
    x, y = xs
    return (x-1)**2 + (y-2)**4

def print_callback(xs):
    """
    Callback called after every iteration.

    xs is the estimated location of the optimum.
    """
    print xs

minimize(objective_function, x0 = (0., 0.), callback=print_callback)
```

Often, one wants to retain information between different calls to the callback, such as, for instance, the iteration number. One way to do this is to use a closure:

```
def generate_print_callback():
    """
    Generate a callback that prints 

        iteration number | parameter values | objective function

    every tenth iteration.
    """
    saved_params = { "iteration_number" : 0 }
    def print_callback(xs):
        if saved_params["iteration_number"] % 10 == 0:
            print "{:3} | {} | {}".format(
                saved_params["iteration_number"], xs, objective_function(xs))
        saved_params["iteration_number"] += 1
    return print_callback
```

Call the minimize function with:

```
minimize(objective_function, x0 = (0., 0.), callback=generate_print_callback())
```